# How to set signals for each action in QMenu?

Tags: qt, qmenu, qaction

```
    for(auto s :listofPossibleValues){
        // item =s;

        action = myMenu.addAction("Set Value to "+s);

        connect(action,SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),this,SLOT(menuClicked()));
    }
  void MainWindow::menuClicked(){
    value = new QStandardItem(item);
    model->setItem(mainindex->row(),mainindex->column(),value);
}
```

I add actions and connect signals to the slot to my menu using the code above.  Previously I was using the item to be the text. But it will only work for last item.

Does anyone at least know how to get the action that I clicked on?
How can I make it work for each individual item rather than just the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [triggered signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#triggered) of `QMenu`:

```
connect(menu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(menuClicked(QAction*)));
```

Then, in `menuClicked()`:

```
void MainWindow::menuClicked(QAction *action) {
    // do something with action
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. but i keep getting the error - no matching function for call to 'connect' I have changed the parameters in both header and class file. How can i fix it please? there is no triggered in my menu. My menu is in a table

Comment: Please show me your connect statement and the exact error message.

Comment: statement - connect(myMenu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(menuClicked(QAction*)));

159: error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'
            connect(myMenu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(menuClicked(QAction*)));
            ^~~~~~~

Comment: Is `myMenu` a pointer? If not, you'll have to use `&myMenu` instead. I'm not sure what you mean by `there is no triggered in my menu`. Is the menu not a `QMenu`?

Comment: yeah it wasnt a pointer thats why it wasnt working. Thanks so much